# Onprem sftp server to EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, file-transfer, amazon-efs

I have a onprem sftp server containing files I need to put in an AWS EFS solution, how can I go about doing this? Can I mount an EFS to the sftp server? Would I need to utilize AWS Transfer Family Service to keep the sftp type of transfer while transferring from the onprem solution to the EFS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [AWS Transfer for SFTP service for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-for-s3/) can _replace_ your on-premises SFTP server, but it will store files in Amazon S3. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* store it on Amazon EFS, then you have two options:

- **Option 1:** Mount the EFS filesystem on an Amazon EC2 instance. Download the files from SFTP to the Amazon EC2 instance and store it on EFS.
- **Option 2:** Install and AWS Direct Connect fiber connection and mount Amazon EFS directly on the SFTP server. See: [Amazon EFS Update – On-Premises Access via Direct Connect | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-efs-update-on-premises-access-via-direct-connect-vpc/)